# Multiple sections in UITableView and UIButtons swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableView that has sections (Category0, Category1,..), and every row of a specific section is a UITableView that has one section which is the question (Question1,..) and rows which are the options to be answered (option1, option2,..).
The problem is when I click on a button in a specific category and a specific question (Category0, question1, option0) see screenshot1,
[image]

immediately another buttons in another categories are clicked (Category1, question2, option0) see screenshot2,

[image]

and (Category4, question1, option0) see screenshot3.

[image]

the code below:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as?  insideTableViewCell

    cell?.answerlabel.text = "option \(indexPath.row)"


    cell?.initCellItem(id: (myObject?.id)! , answer: (myObject?.answerArray![indexPath.row] as? String)!)
    return cell!

}
```

In a custom UITableViewCell which is insideTableViewCell:

```
     func initCellItem(id: Int , answer: String) {

        radioButton.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "unchecked"), for: .normal)
        radioButton.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "checked"), for: .selected)

        radioButton.tag = id
        radioButton.setTitle(answer, for: UIControlState.disabled)
        radioButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.radioButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

  @objc func radioButtonTapped(_ radioButton: UIButton) {
        print(radioButton.tag)
        print(radioButton.title(for: UIControlState.disabled) as Any)
        let answer = radioButton.title(for: UIControlState.disabled) as Any
        let StrId = String(radioButton.tag)
        defaults.set(answer, forKey: StrId)
        let isSelected = !self.radioButton.isSelected
        self.radioButton.isSelected = isSelected
        if isSelected {
            deselectOtherButton()
        }
    }

  func deselectOtherButton() {
        let tableView = self.superview as! UITableView

        let tappedCellIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: self)!
        let section = tappedCellIndexPath.section
        let rowCounts = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)

        for row in 0..<rowCounts {
            if row != tappedCellIndexPath.row {
                let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: row, section: section)) as! insideTableViewCell
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cells are reused, and/or the way you handle the selection is wrong. But without code, that's hard to say...

Comment: You have to keep track of selection objects in your datasource. so when cell is resued you can set it from there !! as @Larme suggests

Comment: you should store the selection and reload tableView

Comment: You should store current buttons state (maybe in dict like [IndexPath: Bool] or some other), and restore it in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Check my answer and follow this format

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted code still guessing.

You can create model object like

```
class QuestionData {
    var strQuestion:String? // This may contains Question
    var strOptions:[String]? // It may contains options titles of your buttons
    var selectedAnswerIndex:Int? // When any button tapped 
}
```

And you should create category models like

```
class Categories {
    var categoryTitle:String? 
    var questions:[QuestionData] = []
}
```

you can use this  `Categories` class as main source of your dataSource array

```
var arrayDataSource = [Categories]()
```

And fill this with your original data.

now whenever any button tapped you can use  `selectedAnswerIndex:Int` to store current selected option for question. and if it is null then user has not selected any option yet.

I have created class so it is reference type you can directly set the value without worry

Hope it is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

There has some and simple code I think it will help you :- if it is not sutable for you pls don't mind :-

```
 if (!btnGreen3.isSelected)
    {
        btnGreen3.isSelected = !btnGreen3.isSelected
    }
    btnBlue3.isSelected = false
    btnBlack3.isSelected = false
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the states of every cell.

The reason is you are using `dequereuseable cell with identifier` when you scroll it switch to another cell.

So make Array or Dictionary where save the state of every selected and unselected Rows.