# how to create custom radio button on ui table view cell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, radio-button

[image]

I need to create custom radio button`s in table view in Swift which would be more than 2 buttons in 1 cell. It would let only 1 button be selected at a time in one cell.

Now I have created buttons where more than 1 button are selected.

Comment: checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783586/4601900

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code about what you've attempted to get specific feedback about where you could be going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to make all buttons background clear

```
func clearButtons() {
 button1.backgroundColor = .clear
 button2.backgroundColor = .clear
 button3.backgroundColor = .clear
 button4.backgroundColor = .clear
 button5.backgroundColor = .clear
 }
```

call this func in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`
Also make `Ib-Action of all buttons` and call this method on every button Tapped IBAction forExample if button1 is pressed you have to do like this

```
 @IBAction func Button1Tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    clearButtons()
 button1.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

same thing you have to do in all buttons action and change the button name which is pressed.

hope its help....

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cell that contains a collectionView (as a component), set it to single selection and override the selected method of UICollectionViewCell to change the colors and stuff...